# How to search if path exists in a directory recursively with python?

Tags: python, file

Hello I want to know whether a path exists in a directory recursively.
I wrote a script but it is too slow.
So I want to know there are any other approaches.
'path' is a partial string of a full path.

```
    bMatch = False
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
        for f in filenames :
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            logger.error(full_path)
            if path in full_path :
                bMatch = True
                logger.error("Matched")
                break
        if bMatch == True :
            break
    if bMatch == False :
        logger.error("[Error] Path doesn't exist. Please check " + path + ' in the row ' + str(row + 1))
```

Comment: What are the packages you are using, where does the variable `path` comes from... Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you say "path is a partial string", do you mean it is some parent folder or e.g. `c:\ag` as a partial string of `c:\agnes`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir` and store the op into a `queue`.Then you can verify the path. Refer my [toy project](https://github.com/Maannniii/file_lister) to know how I'm filtering out directories and files both hidden as well as visible. You will get a basic idea about handling files and directories there.